# ASP.NET Get Control Value By Name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having RadioButtonList as rbQ1,rbQ2,rbQ3 like this upto rbQ13.

Now I would like to loop through this radiobuttons to get the selected value of these radiobuttons.

I tried

```
Dim myControl1 As Control = FindControl("rbQ1")
Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(" & myControl1.selecteditem.value & ");</script")
```

Which is not working and showing the below error.

> Error 16  'selecteditem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'

Comment: you need to cast it as a radiobutton. Control is a generic object representing the basic properties of _all_ types of controls - and clearly not all of them have selected items.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)  Could you please post your suggestion as Answer so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it as a `RadioButton`. `Control` is a generic object representing the basic properties of all types of controls - and clearly not all of them have selected items.